# Nginx Openresty - Change http status after reading the response body

Tags: nginx, proxy, openresty

I have an openresty nginx to proxy elasticsearch. So the grafana client contacts nginx and nginx in return fetches the response from elasticsearch. The goal is to change the http status to 504 if the response body from the elasticsearch contains the key **"timedout": true**

The response body is read using **body_by_filter_lua_block** but this directive doesn't support to change the http status.

```
http {
 lua_need_request_body on;
 server {
 listen 8000;
 location / {
    proxy_pass "http://localhost:9200"
    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        ngx.header.content_length = nil

         }
     body_filter_by_lua_block {
        if string.find(ngx.arg[1], "\"timedout\":true") then
          ngx.arg[1] = nil
        }
      }
 }
}
```

The above code just makes the response body nil . But Is there a way to change the http status ? Or if it's not supported in nginx , is there any other proxy server which can do this job ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change a status within `body_filter_by_lua_block`, because at this moment all response headers already sent downstream.

If you definitely need it - don't use `proxy_pass`.

Instead use `content_by_lua_block` and within it use [lua-resty-http](https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http) to issue a request, read full body, analyze it and respond with any status code you want.

This approach is full buffered and may have significant performance implication for big responses.

Also you should keep in mind that body may be compressed.